# jquery-fileupload-rails - broken form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a [jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) gem to allow multi-file uploader on my website.

I've done everything just like it's written in documentation + i've followed the [example app](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) but all i can get is this view output and none of those buttons work:

[image]

---

My files:

**application.html.haml** (the js and css files are included in assets pipeline)

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body{ :class => yield(:body_class) }

    = yield

  = yield :scripts

  = javascript_include_tag "application"
  = javascript_include_tag "rest_in_place"
```

**uploader.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Upload file</h2>
  <%= form_for UserPhoto.new, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
      <div class="span7">
        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
          <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
          <span>Add files...</span>
          <%= f.file_field :photo %>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
          <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
          <span>Start upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
          <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
          <span>Cancel upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
          <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <!-- The global progress bar -->
        <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
          <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
    <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
    <br>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
    </table>
  <% end %>

</div>
<script>
  var fileUploadErrors = {
  maxFileSize: 'File is too big',
  minFileSize: 'File is too small',
  acceptFileTypes: 'Filetype not allowed',
  maxNumberOfFiles: 'Max number of files exceeded',
  uploadedBytes: 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size',
  emptyResult: 'Empty file upload result'
  };
</script>

<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
    <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
    {% if (file.error) { %}
    <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
    <td>
      <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
      </button>
      {% } %}</td>
    {% } else { %}
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
      <button class="btn btn-warning">
        <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
      </button>
      {% } %}</td>
  </tr>
  {% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
      {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
          {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
      <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
          <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% } %}
</script>
```

**application.js**

```
$(function(){
  // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
  jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload();
  // 
  // Load existing files:
  jQuery.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
    var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload'), 
      template;
    fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
    console.log(files);
    template = fu._renderDownload(files)
      .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
    // Force reflow:
    fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
      template[0].offsetWidth;
    template.addClass('in');
    jQuery('#loading').remove();
  });
});
```

If you can see anything i've done wrong or you need more code to check, please let me know about it, i feel quite desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome's Developer Tools are helpful tracking JS issues down. Get Chrome, then go to the menu -> Tools -> Developer Tools. Click on the right-most Console tab. Refresh to page. Get any errors? (post them here)